# FreeRadius not encode data for rlm_rest in dynamic-client implementation

Tags: freeradius

I'm building a flask based web-service tobe backend of freeradius
Have no problem on Authorization and accounting

Now I want to use freeradius dynamic client with this web-service

My Freeradius version

```
root@freeradius ~# freeradius -v       
radiusd: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.21, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Sep  3 2021 at 14:47:35
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.21
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
```

dynamic-client site config

```
root@freeradius ~# cat /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/dynamic-clients
#
#  Define a network where clients may be dynamically defined.
client dynamic {
    ipaddr = 192.168.56.0/24
    #  Define the virtual server used to discover dynamic clients.
    dynamic_clients = dynamic_clients
    lifetime = 3600
}

#
#  This is the virtual server referenced above by "dynamic_clients".
server dynamic_clients {

    #
    #  The only contents of the virtual server is the "authorize" section.
    authorize {
        rest

    }
}
```

rlm_rest config

```
root@freeradius ~# cat /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/rest 
rest {
    #
    #  This subsection configures the tls related items
    #  that control how FreeRADIUS connects to a HTTPS
    #  server.
    #
    tls {
    }

    connect_timeout = 10.0

    authorize {
        uri = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/radius/authorize"
        method = 'post'
            body = JSON
        #tls = ${..tls}
    }
    authenticate {
    }

    #  Preacct/Accounting/Post-auth/Pre-Proxy/Post-Proxy
    #
    #  Code   Meaning       Process body  Module code
    #  204    no content    no            ok
    #  2xx    successful    yes           ok/updated
    #  5xx    server error  no            fail
    #  xxx    -             no            invalid
        preacct {
        }
    accounting {
        uri = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/radius/accounting"
        method = 'post'
            body = JSON
        #tls = ${..tls}
    }
    post-auth {
    }
    pre-proxy {
    }
    post-proxy {
    }

    #
    #  The connection pool is new for 3.0, and will be used in many
    #  modules, for all kinds of connection-related activity.
    #
    pool {
        start = ${thread[pool].start_servers}

        min = ${thread[pool].min_spare_servers}

        max = ${thread[pool].max_servers}

        spare = ${thread[pool].max_spare_servers}

        uses = 0

        retry_delay = 30

        lifetime = 0

        idle_timeout = 60

    }
}
```

part of flask script that will handle all authorization

```
@app.route('/radius/authorize', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_radius_authorize():
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        return "<p>This is radius Authorize</p>"

    radius_data = request.json
    print(f'app.auth:{radius_data}')
    radius_vserver = request.headers.get('X-Freeradius-Server', None)
    try :
        if radius_vserver == 'dynamic_clients':
            result = proc_dynclient(radius_data)
        else:
            result = proc_authorize(radius_data)

        jresponse = json.dumps(result['response'])
        print(f'\nAuthorize Resp:\n{jresponse}\n')
        return jsonify(result['response']), result['status']
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        return jsonify({}), 500
```

but when the radius client (a mikrotik PPPoE server) make a connection to free radius ,
the flask script didn't receive any post data.
the debug console said

```
app.auth:{}
DynClient:
{}
```

while the FreeRadiuis debug said

```
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) server dynamic_clients {
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/dynmic-clients
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0)   authorize {
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0)     modsingle[authorize]: calling rest (rlm_rest)
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: rlm_rest (rest): Reserved connection (0)
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: Expanding URI components
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: http://127.0.0.1:5000
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: literal --> http://127.0.0.1:5000
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: EXPAND http://127.0.0.1:5000
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest:    --> http://127.0.0.1:5000
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: /radius/authorize
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: literal --> /radius/authorize
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: EXPAND /radius/authorize
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest:    --> /radius/authorize
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: Sending HTTP POST to "http://127.0.0.1:5000/radius/authorize"
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: Adding custom headers:
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest:   X-FreeRADIUS-Section: authorize
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest:   X-FreeRADIUS-Server: dynamic_clients
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: Request body content-type will be "application/json"
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: JSON Data: {}
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: Returning 2 bytes of JSON data
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest: Processing response header
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest:   Status : 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : json (application/json)
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : ERROR: (0) rest: Server returned:
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : ERROR: (0) rest: {}
Sat Dec  2 03:49:45 2023 : Debug: rlm_rest (rest): Released connection (0)
```

Why FreeRadius lokks like did not endcode any data to json for the rest-backend?
Is there any configuration fault? how to fix it?

Note: Some years ago I also played the same thing ... and as far as i remember freeradius will will give me (at least) kind of 'Packet-Src-IP-Address' in JSON format

Sincerely
-bino-

Comment: @arran-cudbard-bell kindly please help me in case you have spare time. I really lost